# View not binding dropdown value of model when sending model back to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following view:

```
@model BusinessModels.ClientBusinessModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Client", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "leads-creation-form js-leads-creation-formr" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModeOfTransport)
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModeOfTransport, new SelectList(ViewBag.TransportList, "Text", "Value"), "")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeOfContainer)
                    <div>
                        <select id="TypeOfContainer" name="TypeOfContainer">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
}

<script>
    $("#ModeOfTransport").on("change", function(){
        showValue($(this).val());
        $("#TypeOfContainer").empty();
            })

            function showValue(val)
            {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetContainerList", "Client")' + "&value=" + val, function (result) {

                    var data = result.data;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //console.log(data[i].value);
                        $("<option />", {
                            val: data[i].Text,
                            text: data[i].Value
                        }).appendTo("#TypeOfContainer");
                        //$("#TypeOfContainer").append("<option>" + data[i].Value + "</option>")

                    }

                })
            }
</script>
```

My GetContainerList is returns a list of values for a dropdown depending on the calue selected in the first dropdown, ModeOfTransport.
This is ok.
However upon submitting the form, I do get the values selected in both dropdown in the model.
My action is below:

```
    public ActionResult Client(ClientBusinessModel clientBusinessModel)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> transportList = GetModeOfTransport();
        ViewBag.TransportList = transportList;
        return View("Index", clientBusinessModel);
    }
```

But when I return the same view, only the first dropdown, ModeOfTransport, gets the value of the clientBusinessModel model.

The dropdown TypeOfContainer does not contain the value of the model, clientBusinessModel.

Upon some investigation I have noticed that the reason behind this problem is because I am not using DropDownListFor for the second property, TypeOfContainer.

Any idea of how to solve this?
Maybe I can send the json value as a string and then use it in the DropDownListFor. Something like :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeOfContainer, new SelectList(StringFromJSON, "Text", "Value"), "")
```

Comment: That is not good code for generating cascading dropdownlists for many reasons. Suggest you refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : you are cool! thanks